# why am i getting a TypeError when I am comparing two integers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = np.array([["M", 86],
              ["M", 76],
              ["M", 56],
              ["M", 66],
              ["B", 16],
              ["B", 13],
              ["B", 16],
              ["B", 18],
              ["B", 14], ])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a, columns=["Case", "radius"])
print(df)

print(df.columns)
a = df[(df["radius"] >= 57) & (df["Case"] == "M")]["radius"].tolist()
print(a)
```

I get an error -
**TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'**
But here i am putting a condition on a column that contains integers. What is the problem here?
i want to have a list of column radius values where the values of column radius are greater than or equal to 57 and "Case"=="M

Comment: Column type for radius is object. It will work when you convert it: df["radius"].astype(int) >= 57

Comment: np.arrays are a single type. Since you start with a np.array the type of that array is object. If you had used a list the dtypes would've been correct when turning into a dataframe. You could also use `df = df.convert_dtypes()` to fix all the dtypes in the frame.

Comment: Start with `a` as list rather than array.  And check the `df.dtypes` before trying to do the testing

Answer (score 0):

Typecast the `radius` column after creating the df, it should work:

```
df.radius = df.radius.astype(int)
```